Parsing error in ASP.NET Core controller - want to receive JSON as string
I'm currently writing an ASP.NET Core web service and I want to setup an endpoint receiving JSON data in a string. I don't want to have it parsed before the endpoint starts.
I've defined this endpoint:
[HttpPost]
[Route("pushjson/{channelCode}")]
public async Task<string> PushJson(string channelCode,
    [FromBody]string jsonData)
{
    return await mediator.Send(new PushJsonCommand(channelCode, jsonData));
}

I'm sending a standard request with a JSON object in the body and I get the following error:

Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1.
The jsonData field is required.

So it seems that the framework tries to parse the provided data, which is definitely not expected. The following code will decide how to handle and process the JSON data based on the configuration, so a pre-parsing is just a waste of time.
How can I configure this endpoint to tell the framework to only store the body data unprocessed and unparsed into a string and provide it to my method?
Changing the code to receive a JObject lets the code work, but then I do have an unneeded parsing and an unneeded serialization which costs CPU time for nothing.
[HttpPost]
[Route("pushjson/{channelCode}")]
public async Task<string> PushJson(string channelCode,
                                   [FromBody]JObject jsonData)
{
    return await mediator.Send(new PushJsonCommand(channelCode, JsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonData)));
}


From what I remember, you cannot specify any arguments and then you have to read the content yourself. It is basically the notion "either the framework is doing the job with given assumptions, or it is completely up to you". Here is post about it for example: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/dec/13/accepting-raw-request-body-content-with-aspnet-web-api

JSON is a string, so the question itself doesn't make a lot of sense.  What's the Content-Type header of the POST call? If it's application/json, ASP.NET Core is doing what you told it to do. If the payload isn't JSON, what is it?

If the call doesn't have a Content-Type, the client has a bug. The server can't just guess what the payload is - XML? JSON? FORM data? Some custom format? In 2024 the sensible default is to assume JSON. If you want a different behavior you can change it.

In ASP.NET Core, the default behavior for [FromBody] is to deserialize the JSON data into a model object. When you pass a string to [FromBody], ASP.NET Core still expects to deserialize it, leading to the error you're encountering.
You could manually read the body stream and treat it as a plain string like below:
[HttpPost]
[Route("pushjson/{channelCode}")]
public async Task<string> PushJson(string channelCode)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
    {
        string jsonData = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        return await mediator.Send(new PushJsonCommand(channelCode, jsonData));
    }
}


Seems ASP.NET automatically parses the body using JsonSerializer, see remarks here:

Remarks
By default, ASP.NET Core MVC delegates the responsibility of reading
the body to an input formatter. In the case of ASP.NET Core Minimal
APIs, the body is deserialized by JsonSerializer.

I'd wager that, when you've got an [HttpPost] that doesn't specify the Content Type that it consumes, it's assumed to be "application/json", try adding this attribute above your endpoint:
[Consumes("text/plain")]

Hi Maxylan, but this requires, that 3rd party consumers of the endpoint always use this media type instead of the "correct" media type 'application/json'.

Figured that could be a concern @peter. As a last-ditch effort I'd look into ActionFilterAttribute then. If that doesn't pan out, however, then you might have to.. A) Trust & Verify that your consumers will send valid json, your route is named 'pushjson/..' after all.. or B) Swallow the added overhead of using JObject as your type, letting ASP.NET parse the request body.
